# Can anyone recommend a jquery menu like reuters.com?

Tags: jquery, menu

I am looking for a jquery menu which mouse hoverover every item that could show a div.(the divs should always show on the same position)
I am not sure whether there have a free jquery menu like [reuters.com](http://reuters.com)

If is there anyone know, could anyone recommend one? I am appreciate for your help.

Comment: Those are absolutely positioned DIVs that are displayed on hover. Nothing special...

Comment: @Šime Vidas， your mean this is only a simple javascript could do it? But why I look the source, the hidden div's content is empty? They are load like a iframe? I am sorry my limited knowledge.

Comment: Yes, only a few lines of JavaScript are required to make this work. I think, you could even do it without JavaScript via the `:hover` selector.

Comment: @Šime Vidas , thanks, I will try myself. But I think if jquery have, it will be more beauty than a `:hover` selector or a `JavaScript`. So If someone see a more advanced and more beauty example, I am also glad to know more.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." Reference: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend going with something DIY like this:

<strike>http://www.jsfiddle.net/Trufa/T5wJv/2/</strike>

If not maybe something like [this](http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/drop-down-menu-jquery-css.html) will help you out, check out the [demo](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/drop-down-menu/#).

Ok, here is a fix, do you like this one:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/Trufa/GXRYb/2/

Comment: if mouse in the `Something other` section ,the div will hidden, i think the div should be showed for the content in the div also are menus, people need have a look and choose.

Comment: @cj333 oh damn, let me fix that! sorry!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have read the drop-down-menu, I think now I know how to do something by myself.

Comment: Glad to help, please tell me if you need anything else! good luck!!